# Should PVC DVW landscape pipe be glued?

Tags: drainage, drain-waste-vent

I'm re-routing a section of 4" landscape drain.  "Triple-wall" pipe was initially installed and has been pinched almost completely closed by a nearby tree, so I'm installing Sch 40 DWV pipe and routing as far around the roots as possible.

The original drain network is not glued.  I've seen varying opinions online about glue vs. no glue on DWV landscape drain applications. I'm leaning toward adhesive just to prevent root incursion, but want to ensure that there aren't any pros/cons or other considerations that I'm missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I chatted with a friend that is a landscape/garden installer.  He strongly recommended gluing each joint to keep roots out of the drain system.

His take was that less expensive landscape contractors will skip the glue step since it takes extra time and most homeowners don't know or care what's buried in their yards - most folks just want the lowest price.

Answer (score 0):

I would thoroughly recommend gluing them, based on what happened to our sewage pipe a few years ago.  We had bought a 10 year old house and everything was fine.  It had a large Norfolk pine in the front yard.

One morning I looked out the window and spotted white roses all over the lawn.  I commented to my wife who said there aren't any roses there.  It turned out be loo paper, that come out of back vents etc from the sewage pipe.

Had to hire a contractor with a digger who found unsealed pipes with roots from the Norfolk pine in them.  On breaking open the pipe, it was totally blocked with roots.  This was not the expensive part.  The expensive part was getting the tree chopped down (in the middle of suburbia) to the tune of $5000.

Answer (score -1):

I've only heard of triple wall pipe in terms of venting on combustion appliances where cold air and hot air pass by each other - did they use chimney vent pipe for landscape drainage?

Are you using schedule 40 4" pvc with perforated holes on the bottom for water table drainage or is this solid pvc pipe that is going to be used for rain water removal?

If the pipe has the holes in the bottom to allow water table water to come up into the pipe then I don't see an advantage to gluing it.  If the pipe is for rain water management or surface drainage and is solid then it makes sense to glue it.  It isn't a huge cost or effort to glue it and it should stop root infiltration.

Curious about what reasons someone could have to not glue the pipe, what have you found?

Comment: There is "triple wall" drain pipe - it's PVC and ABS, inexpensive and fairly flexible.  I am using non-perf pipe (this is not a French drain).  Best reason to not glue is ease of rework and ease of assembly.

Answer (score -1):

I’ve had drain pipes in the ground for ten years in the desert with no roots, glue or problems…also had a palm tree with roots next to pipe and no issues..if I lived in a place with more trees I would have glued…..

Comment: Yes there are no roots in the desert and palm tree roots being fibrous are not invasive.